# Does selenium support devexpress grid to record and playback using selenium IDE?

Tags: grid, devexpress, selenium-rc

I have a web app which contains devexpress grid. I tried to click the link displayed in one of the column of the grid, but it doesn't capture anything. Can anyone help me to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Selenium works with DevExpress controls, but the Selenium IDE recorder often fails to detect the correct element in which case you need to replace the 'Target' parameter with a manually entered one.  You can use Firebug or equivalent to help find likely targets.  Also, it sometimes helps to replace 'click' with a 'mouseDown' followed by a 'mouseUp'.

For instance, the following script works for clicking on rows and columns:

```
// open the DevExpress grid demo (tested against version 11.2.5)
selenium.open("http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx");

// click on the City column header
selenium.mouseDown("//td[@id='ContentHolder_grid_col3']/table/tbody/tr/td");
selenium.mouseUp("//td[@id='ContentHolder_grid_col3']/table/tbody/tr/td");

// click on the each of the first three rows
selenium.click("//tr[@id='ContentHolder_grid_DXDataRow0']/td/a");
selenium.click("//tr[@id='ContentHolder_grid_DXDataRow1']/td/a");
selenium.click("//tr[@id='ContentHolder_grid_DXDataRow2']/td/a");
```